# custom form message conflict with validate()

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have created a form. However my script for customizing form error messages does not display. Only the default error message shows on validation.

I have created a form previously where both work perfectly fine together. The only difference being now I am using formlabels.js to make the labels disappear on the form.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/additional-methods.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the validate code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example_contact').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    errorElement: 'div',
    // your other rules and options
    position: "center right",
offset: [8,15]
    });

});


</script>
```

This is the formlabels  js file:

```
<script src="js/jquery.formLabels.js"></script> 

<link type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://o2v.net/wp-content/plugins/syntax-highlighter-and-code-prettifier/styles/shCore.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://o2v.net/wp-content/plugins/syntax-highlighter-and-code-prettifier/styles/shThemeDefault.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://o2v.net/wp-content/plugins/syntax-highlighter-and-code-prettifier/scripts/shCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://o2v.net/wp-content/plugins/syntax-highlighter-and-code-prettifier/scripts/shBrushCss.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://o2v.net/wp-content/plugins/syntax-highlighter-and-code-prettifier/scripts/shBrushJScript.js"></script>
```

This is also a formlabels .js file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/init.js"></script>
```

Here is the code for the custom error message. I have it in an external .js file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
required: "This is a required field.",
remote: "Please fix this field.",
email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
url: "Please enter a valid URL.",
date: "Please enter a valid date.",
dateISO: "Please enter a valid date (ISO).",
number: "Please enter a valid number.",
digits: "Please enter only digits.",
creditcard: "Please enter a valid credit card number.",
equalTo: "Email and Confirm Email fields do not match",
accept: "Please enter a value with a valid extension.",
maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter no more than {0} characters."),
minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter at least {0} characters."),
rangelength: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1} characters long."),
range: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1}."),
max: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value less than or equal to {0}."),
min: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value greater than or equal to {0}.")
});
</script>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="form_container">   
    <form method="post" action="/cgi-bin/form-mail.cgi" name="example_contact" id="example_contact">
    <input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="you@your-domain-hosting-this-script.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="env_report" value="REMOTE_HOST,REMOTE_ADDR,HTTP_USER_AGENT">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="thankyou.html">

        <div id="form_block">
            <p class="field_n"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" title="Name" minlength="5" maxlength="12" /></p>

            <p class="field_e"><input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="required email" title="Email*" /></p>

            <p class="field_ce"><input type="email" name="emailConfirm" id="emailConfirm" class="required email" equalTo='#email' title="Confirm Email*" /></p>

            <p class="field_T"><textarea rows="10" cols="28" id="message" name="message" title="Message*" class="required"></textarea></p>
        </div>

        <ul class="check_box">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="terms" name="terms" value="terms" class="required"/>
                <label for="terms"><span class="check"></span>Click here to accept our <a class="terms_link" href="terms.html">terms of service</a><span class="asterix">&#42;</span></label>                   
            </li>
        </ul>
        <p class="submit"><button type="submit">SUBMIT</button></p>

        </form> 
    </div>
```

If anyone can help I am grateful. I have tried removing all the script references but it still didn't work. The only thing that made a difference was using no conflict but all that achieved was to make the error messages disappear completely. I am just a web designer with basic js skills from years ago that I can't remember. So can answers can be displayed as simply as possible please :o)

Comment: I have noticed that the error message being displayed is not even the default error messages. The error message displayed is actually the title tag. `<p class="field_n"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" title="Name" minlength="5" maxlength="12" /></p>` How can I get it to display even just the default error messages and not the title tag?

Comment: ok, I know why it is displaying the title. Because J query validate() will display the title of an input tag as it's error message!

Comment: Can this error message from the title input tag be overridden?

Comment: Ok Fixed it. I just added: `ignoreTitle: true`